# Classify all groups of order 1225

Tags: group-theory

Ok,

so this was a recent question I've been asked for homework. "Classify all groups of order $1225$". That's all the question says. How in the world do I approach this?? We have the symmetric group of order $1225$, cyclic group of order $\,1225 = 5*5*7*7\,$ and so we have that as a group.. but the list just seems so big. How do we classify **all** groups of this order, it's huge! We had a similar question on groups of order $8$ the other week and it wasn't easy..

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Such questions can very often be addressed using knowledge of the classification of Abelian Groups, and Sylow's theorems to get a handle on possible nonabelian groups.

Comment: There's no such a thing as "the symmetric group of order $1225$", as there isn't any natural $n$ such that $n!=1225$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

1) Prove there are exactly one Sylow 5-subgroup and one Sylow 7-subgroup

2) Prove that every group of order the square of a prime number is abelian

3) Show thus that any group of order $\,1225\,$ is abelian and thus

4) There are only $\,4\,$ groups of order $\,1225\,$ (Using the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups)

Comment: that really helps, thanks a ton!

Comment: how you concluded from 2 -> 3? if I have 2 groups that are abelian, their multiplication must be also abelian, I don't believe that is true.

Comment: @thecorrectanswer I'm not sure what you ask. We have that $\;1225 = 25*49\;$, and the subgroups of order $\;25, 49\;$  are normal by (1), Thus, a group of order $\;1225\;$ is a direct product of two group of order the square of a prime...and we[re done by (2). What isn't clear to you?